# "Cannot reslove symbol 'springframework'"

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, annotations

Im working on a full stack webapplication and suddenly when i opened Intellij ultimate, i got the error  ["Cannot reslove symbol 'springframework'"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGNjl.png), over and over again.

After clicking on import IntelliJ installed some Jar files but i guess not all because all annotations i used aren't recognised any more.

I opened my project in the community version of IntelliJ and there's no problem with it. I need to work on my project in the ultimate edition, because of the plugins i use in the frontend.

Does anyone else know what went wrong and how i could solve this?

I'm using Spring boot (Java 11) with gradle on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by reinstalling intelliJ and install all plugins again

Answer (score 0):

Please clean your pom file and then build it.
Also, check the settings in IntellliJ -> Module Settings
Check the SDKs etc.
Also go to Preferences -> Build,Execution,Deployment-> Compiler -> Java Compiler
to check your Target bytecode version

Comment: The sdk is correct, it shows the java 11 version. Does gradle have a pom file?